# Put cursor.fetchone to specific row?

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm working on a project where I need to get data from my SQL Server, but there is a catch. In total there is around 100.000 rows in the specific column I need the data out of but I only need the last 20.000 - 30.000 rows of it.

I use the casual connection string and stored procedure but is there a way to select a specific row to start from? (for example let it start at row 70.000)

```
try:
    CONNECTION_STRING = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+databaseName+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password

    conn = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    storedproc = "*"
    cursor.execute(storedproc)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        
        OID = ((int(row[1])))
        print(OID)
```

So my question: is there a way (for example) set `cursor.fetchone` to row 70.000 instead of 1? Or is there another way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use an `ORDER BY` and `OFFSET...FETCH` in your SQL if you want the "70th" row? Though you can't do that with a Stored Procedure, you would have to do that with a `SELECT`. If you getting 100 rows from a procedure, and want the 70th row, you would need to `INSERT` that data into a (temporary) table, and then `SELECT` the 70th row from that.

Comment: Alright thanks, then i guess its out of my hands because i do not make the storage procedures. but ill go after the person that does and ill try to edit this with them.